# It is better to have a negative clock skew?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, clock-speed, synchronous

Is it better to have a negative clock skew? Why? If we compare it with a positive clock skew, which is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessarily better, in fact, it depends on which timing is harder to respect. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew), "Positive clock skews are good for fixing setup violations, but can cause hold violations. Negative clock skew can guard against a hold violation, but can cause a setup violation."

The best practice is to design circuits that work well with zero skew. This makes designs much less prone to failures caused by later modifications.

Comment: Well, you *could* add that in general a setup violation can be worked around easily (by lowering the clock frequency) while a hold violation is more difficult to counteract. In general however I fully agree!